# Warning in struts2 application s:property tag

Tags: struts2

I did a Struts2 tutorial and everything works, however I am left with a Warning:

The tag handler class for `<s:property>` (`org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.PropertyTag`) was not found on the *Java* Build Path    `HelloWorld.jsp`

I can't seem to find which library is missing especially since it runs fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2126196/876739

Comment: What is a question and why didn't you post a stacktrace?

Comment: It's a warning, there are no errors, there is no compiling, it's a Java warning.

Comment: Ok I mostly understand @xrcwrn, but I'm confused as to whether they mean the Environment variables? I'm not sure which "extracted clutter" files I'm dealing with exaclty.. in fact the manifest has nothing for the classpath at all.

Comment: You have to download latest version of [struts2](https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/) and put it to ` /WEB-INF/lib`. Better way to use any ide  and find tutorial on it how to use struts2 with that ide.

Comment: listen... It all runs... This is a WARNING, not an ERROR, it can compile, I just don't want an annoying warning, all files are there everything works, I don't know how else to say this, and I'm using eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Move `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>` to the very first line of your jsp - it removes the warning

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem:
Mine was: `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"% >`

I had a space after the last `%`
When I deleted the space it solved all my warnings.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.PropertyTag is contained in Struts 2 Core 2.x.x.x API.

In Jsp file you have to import this tag-lib by adding following import code in top of your jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```

Comment: Yes, I have them, that is what is generating the Java warning.

Comment: Did you copied JAR files to the lib folder in WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Yes this is a simple WARNING, my project works and compiles I just want to get rid of the annoying warning

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After adding `struts2-core-2.1.8.jar`, the warning was gone and my project executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines under the struts tag:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```